# Help with a Telescoping sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My professor gave us this example on her notes:

$$\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { 5 }^{ \frac { n }{ 2 } -1 }\ln { \left( \frac { n+1 }{ n }  \right) \left( n+2 \right) \left( n+3 \right) -{ 2 }^{ \frac { n }{ 2 }  }\left( n+2 \right) \left( n+3 \right) \ln { \left( { \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ \ln { \left( n \right)  }  } \right)  } -2\ln { \left( { \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ \ln { \left( n \right)  }  } \right)  } { 5 }^{ \frac { n }{ 2 } -1 } }  }{ { 5 }^{ \frac { n }{ 2 } -1 }\left( n+2 \right) \left( n+3 \right) \ln { \left( { \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ \ln { \left( n \right)  }  } \right)  }  }  } $$

So I know we're supposed to find the partial fraction, which ends up being

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\dfrac{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})(n+2)(n+3)-2^{\frac{n}{2}}(n+2)(n+3)\ln((n+1)^{\ln(n)})}{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(n+2)(n+3)\ln((n+1)^{\ln(n)})}=\dfrac{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})-2^{\frac{n}{2}}\ln((n+1)^{\ln(n)})}{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\ln((n+1)^{\ln(n)})}$$

$$=\dfrac{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(\ln(n+1)-\ln(n))-2^{\frac{n}{2}}\ln(n)\ln(n+1)}{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\ln(n)\ln(n+1)}=\dfrac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\ln(n)\ln(n+1)}-\dfrac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{5^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{\ln(n)}-\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)}-5(\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}})^{n}$$

So the sum becomes:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}-\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}-5(\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}})^{n})=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}-\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)})-5\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}})^{n}$$

$$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{N}(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}-\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)})-5(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}}-1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}})$$

$$=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{1}{\ln(2)}-\frac{1}{\ln(N+1)})-5(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}}-1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}})=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}-5(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}}-1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}})$$

Comment: You are welcome.